# High wireless latency response at a constant signal power

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am using a Huawei HG8247H at 2.4Ghz mode within a 5000 square feet house. I face trouble with wireless connectivity quite often. I live at a place close to mobile telephone towers. Most of the times all devices connected to the router would work fine, but at some random 10 times during a day, the router's latency response gets so high (sometimes even for 10 minutes) that none of the connected devices work during this time slot regardless of where they exist in the house.

Router's latency responses go as high as 2000ms during this interruption window. A wireless analyzer app "Vistumbler" shows a constant signal power within +/- 10dBm which is why the devices remain connected to the router during this time. Sitting within a feet of the router, also makes no difference. I use Channel 11 as it gives me less frequent problems compared to Auto or any other channel number.

1. Is interference likely to occur when you're that close to the router and signal power is constant?
2. I’m currently testing a second wireless router on channel 1 connected to the main router through LAN to see if the channel gets populated or the whole of 2.4GHz range does during that time slot.

Answer (score 0):

Which frequency band are you on? 2.4GHZ or 5GHz? 2.4GHz happens to be roughly the same wavelength commercial microwave ovens work on, and it does create interference that can go as far as to completely cut your wireless connection off.

Maybe someone nearby is using his/her microwave oven?

Comment: I am using 2.4GHz and within my house no one uses a microwave during that slot. Also my houses is 6000 square feet and independent.

Comment: There goes my theory... Damn... Back to the drawing board. Any obstacles between source and data recipients? Is the router properly ventilated? If it's overheating, its CPU could throttle down, hence the latency.

Comment: Like I said the issue persists even when I’m virtually on top of the router and yes it’s ventilated enough.

Comment: EDIT to my previous comment: what happens when you use an Ethernet cable instead of WiFi? Latency still there?

Comment: a perfect <1ms on LAN.

Comment: So there's definitely a problem with your WiFi, not the router, I think. Client-wise, did you check if your WiFi adapters on the PC's didn't have a power-saving mode enabled? Did you go into your router management settings to check on time-out?

Comment: if you read my question, it’s clear that all connected devices have this issue simultaneously so no issues with clients. There are no timeouts on the router side either. Shall I try a different router on the same channel? I think it’s something in the environment as I have some mobile towers near my house.

Comment: Further, I’ve independently setup another wireless router running a different channel through LAN to the main router as another access point. I will try to monitor if during that poor connectivity window, the other router works fine or not.